# Remove XML namespaces in all nodes but the root node

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

I want to remove the namespaces in all the nodes but leaving ths namespace in the root node.

Do you know how can I do it?

I'm using this XSLT but it's removing the namespaces in all the nodes.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"><xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" />
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" >
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just making sure here... You want to keep the root element in the same namespace, and give all descendants the default (empty) namespace? I'm asking because sometimes people want to just have all namespaces declared in the root element but leave the descendants in their original namespace (without duplicate or redundant prefix bindings).

Comment: Yes, the idea is keep the root element in the same namespace and give all descendants an empty namespace.

Comment: Please provide an example of input and expected output.

Comment: We need to remove the namescapes in all the nodes but the root node.
But we need to keep the prefixes.

In this image you have an example.



Thanks

Comment: This is the image with the example
http://i64.tinypic.com/1zyy4c4.jpg

Answer (score 2):

The simple way to keep an element in its namespace is to **copy** it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- remove namespaces -->
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" >
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!-- keep namespace of root element -->
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that this does not handle attributes (neither does your version).

Comment: Blindly copying the whole root node might produce extra namespace declarations which are not used in the final, ns-stripped document. I still think it is a cleaner option to have the root namespace declared explicitly in the XSL.

Comment: I agree (somewhat) to the first part, but not to the second. Let OP produce an example of the input.

Comment: Thanks, this is working fine.

But this is deleting the namespaces in all the subnodes...

I thought that was what we need, but we need to keep the prexif in all the nodes. Deleting only the URLs.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: @Richal It is doing exactly what you asked for: "*I want to remove the namespaces in all the nodes but leaving ths namespace in the root node.*" If you want something else, I suggest you post a new question and make sure to include an example of the input and the expected output. Note that you cannot use a prefix without binding it to a namespace URI.

Answer (score -1):

Your first approach seems very well aimed to me. You just have to:

- Add a template to match the root node, which won't drop off the namespace:

`<xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:element name="{name()}" >
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>`

- Include in the XSL the root namespace definition:

`<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:rootns="..." >`

Comment: You are assuming that the root element has a prefix. Even then there is a simpler way.